# perfect matching-proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let every vertex of a graph $G$ have $\delta=3$ and let $G$ have no cut-edge. Then prove that $G$ has a perfect matching. A cut edge is an edge whose deletion increases the number of connected components.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you learnt about in class? Could you say what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the so called [Petersen Theorem](http://planetmath.org/PetersensTheorem.html) which can be proven using [Tutte's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem)

Let me know if you need a more in depth proof.

Comment: A more in-depth proof would be fantastic.